# php - regex exclude word between quotes

Tags: php, regex

I want to match all words with `\w` and excluding some specific word and numbers.
but I want to exclude also words between double and single quotes with something like this `(?!"\w+")` but seems doesn't work.

How can I do? Here's what am using

```
/(?!return|if|floor|else|elseif|NULL|null|pow|function|\d+)\b(\w+)/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*F)` predicated in PCRE to match and skip certain substrings like this:

```
/(['"])\w+\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?!return|elseif|else|if|floor|NULL|pow|function|\d+)\w+/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pUJM67/2)

- `(['"])` matches single or double quote and captures it in group #1
- `\w+` matches a single word
- `\1` backrefrence to group #1 to ensure we have same closing quote as in group #1
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` will skip this match